# RightTapped Holding Event Only Happening Once

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the below code but it is only happening once on first hold and not after.

Properly something is very simple but it can't seem to find a answer.

```
private void Contact_Tap_1_Holding(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    contactSelected = 1;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ContactAddPopUp));
}

<Button x:Name="Contact_1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40,464,51,0"
 RightTapped="Contact_Tap_1_Holding" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="72"
 Background="#ff4081" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFFFFF"
 Click="button_Click" Content="Contact 1" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to set `IsRightTapEnabled="True"`? Also it seems that after event is fired, it should navigate to other page - you mean that it doesn't work after returning to previous page?

Comment: Thanks, Yes thats correct, it doesn't work after return to previous page.

Comment: Additionally IsRightTappedEnabled is enabled.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, can you please provide more details such as your device's OS build?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response and wasted effort, this was actually a problem from somewhere else in the code, apologies.